# Div in responsive page ignoring viewport size in mobile browsers

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm working on making my [pet project web app](http://whatitdo.herokuapp.com/) responsive, but I can't get the page to display properly in mobile browsers. My page is basically constructed as a container div, header, navigation bar (which moves from the side to the top when going from desktop to mobile), and a main content div, and all went as expected until I tested on an iPhone (both Safari and Firefox) - the header and nav bar displayed properly, but the content div is way too big and breaks the page. [Here are some screenshots to show you what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LigdC.jpg) (iPhone/Safari at default zoom, iPhone zoomed out to show the full page, and equivalent window size in Firefox).

Confusingly, this only seems to affect the main content div (`.list`), as the header and navigation bar still display at the intended size, but I'm having a hard time seeing anything in the code that would make it behave differently.

Relevant HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
...
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
...
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">


<div id="logoheader"><h1>...</h1><h2>...</h2></div>
<div class="buttonbar">...</div>

<div class="list">
    <h3>...</h3>
    <div class="maintable">
    ...
    ...
    </div>
</div>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#container {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 1250px;
    min-height: 600px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#logoheader {
    width: auto;
    min-width: 888px;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}
.buttonbar {
    position: absolute;
    left: 18px;
    width: 90px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.list {
    position: absolute;
    left: 108px;
    right: 20px;
    min-height: 490px;
    min-width: 750px;
    display: block;
    vertical-align: top;
    white-space: normal;
}
.maintable {
    font-size: .875rem;
    width: auto;
    min-height: 406px;
}

@media screen and ( max-width: 600px ) {
#container {
    max-width: auto;
    min-height: auto;
}
#logoheader {
    min-width: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
}
.buttonbar {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.list {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    min-height: auto;
    min-width: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
.nontable {
    min-height: auto;
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm just wondering why you don't want to use floats instead of applying position absolute for both .buttonbar and .list?

Comment: No particular reason (besides that this was the first site I made and I was scared of floats at the time). Fortunately, those parts work correctly as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CSS styling for `.list`

```
.list {
    position: absolute;
    left: 108px;
    right: 20px;
    min-height: 490px;
    min-width:750px;
    display: block;
    vertical-align: top;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

remove the `min-width:750px` and you're good to go :)

Comment: That worked, thanks! I also found a bunch of other min-widths laying around that were messing up the layout and setting them to either 0 or 100% instead of auto solved my issues.

Comment: Glad it helps. From the code above you're telling the minimum width is 750px. So if you have a device with 320px width screen, the list container will not going to be 320px width, but will remain with that 750px instead

Answer (score 0):

Just add `display:inline` to your media query for the `.list`!

I tested it in responsive layout:

[image]

As you can see the portrait layout has `display: inline` and the landscape doesn't, just to show you the difference!

Comment: I marked Qiqi's answer as correct, but this also worked since `display: inline` removes all sizing from a box, including the min-widths that were giving me trouble. Thanks!